# How to use continue keyword to skip to beginning of a loop in Scala

Tags: scala, continue

How to use continue keyword to skip to beginning of a loop in Scala?

```
while(i == "Y") {
    println("choose an item id between 1 and 4")
    val id = scala.io.StdIn.readInt()
    if(id >= 5) {
        println("not a valid id. please choose again")
        continue
    }
}
```

I know there is breakable and break abstracts provided by Scala but that doesn't seem to achieve my functionality.

Comment: First, can you please format the code correctly? Second, can you be more clear about what you really want, not just _"I want to use `continue`"_. Third, AFAIK this doesn't exist in **Scala**. Fourth, plain imperative while loops and jumps are not really idiomatic in **Scala**.

Comment: I recently learned that breakable originally tried to offer a continue method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scala , java "for" in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47162308/scala-java-for-in-scala)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In functional programming recursion is kind of loop, so consider the following approach

```
@tailrec def readInputRecursively(count: Int): Option[Int] = {
  if (count == 0) {
    println("Failed to choose correct id")
    None
  } else {
    println(s"choose an item id between 1 and 4 ($count remaining attempts)")
    val id = StdIn.readInt()
    if (id >= 5) readInputRecursively(count - 1) else Some(id)
  }
}

readInputRecursively(3).map { input =>
  // do something with input
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to use continue keyword to skip to beginning of a loop in Scala?

There is no `continue` keyword in Scala, so you cannot use the `continue` keyword to skip to the beginning of a loop in Scala, nor can you use it for anything else, since you cannot use something that doesn't exist.